# Yii Layout view files: beginContent() method default value

Tags: php, yii

I am playing with layout in Yii, and have one question need your help.
As I looked into layout view file: "column1.php" I see the beginContent() method:

```
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
```

As I read a guiedbook "Agile web development with Yii", it said: [quote]The view being specified
here is our main layout page 'layouts/main'. If nothing is specified, it will use the default layout
specified either at the controller level, or if not specified at the controller level, at the
application level.[/quote]
As I understand that the layout specified at the controller level is "layout/column1" (as I have checked value $this->layout). so If I leave this layout empty in the beginContent() method, then it will render "layout/column1", am I right?
If so, the new loaded layout will reapeatly load the "layout/colum1" as there's no layout value pass to beginContent() method at this new loaded layout. and I iffer that this will return an error.

But, when I leave this layout value empty. the view file still load as normal. no error occured.
I am very supprised with it.

Could someone tell me what has happened?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your controller class `extend controller`? The layout is also defined in there (/components/Controller.php), and make sure there's no layout defined in your application configuration (/config/main.php)